# Can I run multiple laravel-apps from one main-app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

This might seem to be a silly question but bare with me, i will explain.

Suppose i have 3(can be more) laravel-apps on different topics/purposes.

And i have a main-app, that theoratically can launch the other 3 apps that i talked about.

The way i image it is like this

#### App # 1 Main Page

```
Route::get('/home', 'AppController1@index');
```

#### App # 2 Main Page

```
Route::get('/home', 'AppController2@index');
```

#### App # 3 Main Page

```
Route::get('/home', 'AppController3@index');
```

The above apps are seperate and have their own controllers, files and all other stuff...

#### My-Question

Can i run these apps(somehow) from one main app like this...

```
Route::get('/App1', LaunchApp1SomehowWithAllOfItsRoutesAndFiles) ;

Route::get('/App2', LaunchApp2SomehowWithAllOfItsRoutesAndFiles) ;
```

Is something like this possible or do i have to combine all apps into one to achieve this?

Comment: Why not put all 3 apps on 3 different subdomains?

Comment: Yeah i think that will work, thanks